# Regex: How to match text inside 2 quotes inside 2 commas?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match any text inside quote, which in turn are inside commas, like this:

> Pellentesque habitant,"`morbi, tristique. senectus`", et netus et
>   malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat
>   vitae,"`ultricies "habitant" eget`", yhs tygs.

For example:

> ,"anything here will be a match",

What regex should I use?

Comment: Might be simpler just to split by commas and then filter for those items that start with and end with a quote (or some variant thereof).

Comment: One other thing, standard english grammar usually puts commas and other delimiters inside of quotes, rather than outside (at least for those that end a quotation). Something to keep in mind just in case (http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/quotes.asp).

Comment: The `comma` (`,`) is a punctuation mark - a `coma` is a medical condition (of being unconscious) ....

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, this is what you want:

```
,"(.+?)",
```

Group 1 will contain what you want.

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/eK1zQ7/1)

Or else, if you don't want groups, you can use this:

```
(?<=,").*(?=",)
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/eK1zQ7/2)

Comment: I'm about to test it.

Comment: Why didn't you escape the quote as well? I'm looking for the text the start with a comma, then a quote. It ends with a quote then a comma.

Comment: @Richard77 I've updated everything. You can check it now

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex to match `,"anything",`,

```
,\"[^"]*\",
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xT3pN1/7)